# Redirect To Root Domain With HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

so I'm making a small educational site for a local school. Right now the site is hosted in a sub-domain for development and testing. However, somehow Google managed to crawl my site so whenever I google a topic and the website's name, the sub-domain shows up in the results.

I want to move the site to the main domain and redirect the users visiting the sub-domain to the corresponding route in the main domain.

This is the .htaccess file containing the RewriteRules in the sub-domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^log-in$ index.php?section=log-in [QSA]
RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?section=register [QSA]
RewriteRule ^courses$ index.php?section=courses [QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?section=contact [QSA]
RewriteRule ^instructor$ index.php?section=instructor [QSA]
RewriteRule ^my-profile$ index.php?section=my-profile [QSA]

RewriteRule ^404$ index.php?section=404 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^course/([0-9]+)$ index.php?section=course&course_id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^course/([0-9]+)/lecture-id/([0-9]+)$ index.php?section=course&course_id=$1&lecture_id=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^articles$ index.php?section=articles [QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?section=articles&article_category=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?section=article&slug=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^log-out$ res/php/user_actions/logout.php [QSA]
```

So these are some examples of the redirections that should happen

```
sub.domain.com          => domain.com
sub.domain.com/courses  => domain.com/courses
sub.domain.com/course/5 => domain.com/course/5
sub.domain.com/articles => domain.com/articles
sub.domain.com/article/article-name => domain.com/article/article-name
and so on...
```

I basically want to redirect the user to the same route but on the main domain. Anyone how I can achieve this and manage my redirections properly so my SEO rankings wont get hurt? Ideally I want manage the redirections with an `htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do I have to put this in my sub-domain's htaccess file?

Comment: I would remove the subdomain completely and add what I posted in the main .htaccess file for the site.

If you need to keep the subdomain, you can either paste what I posted in, or just the RewriteRule, since the RewriteCond will always be met in your subdomain.

Comment: Ahh ok, one more question. I see the RewriteRule has en `https` before the domain name. If I don't have an SSL certificate should I just leave it like this: `RewriteRule .* http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` without the `s` in the protocol?